# Test Element on page when request is pending in puppeteer

Tags: jestjs, puppeteer

I use next code to check Request and Response when submit button is clicked:

```
const postRequestInfo = await Promise.all([
            page.waitForRequest(
              request =>
                request.url() === 'https://httpbin.org/status/200' && request.method() === 'POST'
            ),
            page.waitForResponse(
              response =>
                response.url() === 'https://httpbin.org/status/200' && response.status() === 200
            ),
            page.click('[data-hook="async-button__post-submit-btn"]')
          ]);
```

Is there possibility to test property of element when request is pending?

So, I want to execute this piece of code after request was sent but response didn't come yet:

```
 expect(
   await page.$eval('[data-hook="async-button__post-submit-btn"]', el => 
   el.disabled)
 ).toEqual(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this! I should use `page.on`

```
 page.on('request', async interceptedRequest => {
        if (
          interceptedRequest.url() === 'https://httpbin.org/status/200' &&
          interceptedRequest.method() === 'POST'
        ) {
          expect(
            await page.$eval('[data-hook="async-button__post-submit-btn"]', el => el.disabled)
          ).toEqual(true);
        }
        interceptedRequest.continue();
      });
```